# Is there any way to create a loop which fills down values to the next empty 5 rows in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, fillna

I have a `dtype: object` column in my `df` and I would like to fill down values to the empty cells. None of my attempts made the job for me including `df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)`.

So what I did was I converted the column into a list, created a list with values I want to fill down in my column and run the following loop:

```
a = ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']
Name = ["Loaded volume_Road", "Loaded volume_Rail"]

for x in range(len(a)):
    if a[x] not in Name:
        a[x] = a[x-1]
print(a)     

#output:
a = ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail']
```

Then I inserted the list values into my column and this basically did the job.

However later I realised that I need only to fill down value for the next 5 rows as follows:

```
#current output:
a = ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail']

#desired output:
a = ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']
```

Do you have guys any tips how to achieve the `#desired output`? I run out of ideas :-(

Many thanks!!!

Comment: is this question about list or dataframe? In your post i can only see list

Comment: sorry for the confusion....
the question itself is about list, how could I achieve the desired output on it....
and then I insert the list values into a column in my df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
indexes = [i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] != 'nan']

for idx in indexes:
    a[idx: idx + 6] = [a[idx]] * 6
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'Loaded volume_Road', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'Loaded volume_Rail', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']
```

Comment: Perfect! It´s doing exactly what I needed, thank you very much !
Appreciate your help.

Tomas

Comment: for your info with dataframe you could do like this `df.fillna(method='ffill', limit=5)`

Comment: I tried that however it did absolutely nothing....not sure if it has something to do with the dtype is object....and it cannot recognize the "nan" because it is a string value?

Comment: you can replace string `'nan'` with `np.nan` like this `df.loc[df[col].eq('nan'), col] = np.nan`